# Containerizing Python script with read and write access to local files not in project folder

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I store some files in a Google Drive folder and have been running my scripts locally, so that the scripts read files from the GDrive folder and then save some outputs to the GDrive folder.

I now want containerize a script with the function `do_stuff()` so that it can access the `google_drive_folder` to both read data and write to it.

```
import os
from pickle import load, dump
import my_script

google_drive_folder = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Google Drive\\Projects'

source_file_location = os.path.join(google_drive_folder, 'old_data.pickle')
with open(source_file_location, 'rb') as read:
    old_data = load(read)

new_data = my_script.do_stuff(old_data)

target_file_location = os.path.join(google_drive_folder, 'new_data.pickle')
with open(target_file_location, 'wb') as fp:
    dump(new_data, fp)

print(f'File saved to {target_file_location}')
```

The error message I get looks like this, even though when using Windows Explorer I can copy paste that exact path and find the file I'm looking for.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Me/Google Drive/Projects/old_data.pickle'
```

All the scripts are in a folder called `src`. I'm trying to use `docker-compose` and I've tried storing different variables like the folder locations to a `.env` file without success.

So far my docker file looks like this

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY ./src ./src

CMD ["python", "./src/my_script.py"]
```

`docker-compose.yml` looks like this

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: my-scripts
    command: python ./src/my_script.py
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Comment: The error message and the Dockerfile both suggest you're running in a Linux container, which doesn't have a DOS-style `C:` drive.  Instead of hard-coding `google_drive_folder`, can you set it from an environment variable, or use a path relative to the current directory?

Comment: The issue with this is that the project folder is here `C:/Users/Me/Python/<here>` where as the Google drive folder is in `C:/Users/Me/Google Drive/Projects/<here>` so I should somehow be able to go back a few folders to `C:/Users/Me/` in my dockerfile (?) and from there to Google drive, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I did some digging and figured out exactly what I needed to do. The below configurations make it so that data from Google drive is accessible from the container like this

```
source_file_location = os.path.join('data', 'old_data.pickle')
with open(source_file_location, 'rb') as read:
    old_data = load(read)
```

docker-compose.yml which creates a bind mount `data`, but not a folder visible in the file system of the container

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: my-scripts
    command: python ./src/my_script.py
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - type: bind
        source: "C:/Users/Me/Google Drive/Projects"
        target: /code/data
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Dockerfile just builds the image, all the logic related to bridging the host and container folders is in the docker-compose

```
FROM python:3.10-slim
WORKDIR /code
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "./src/my_script.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you are on a container, you are no longer in your "normal OS".

For example, python container is based on linux, as a result, there is no such a folder as `C:\whatever`.

What you have to do here is to use a volume that you will mount where your picke file will be.

## in container realm

You will have a folder, let's call it `/data` and in this folder you will have a `old_data.pickle` file.

When you run your script in the container, it will have to access the /data folder, and will write the `new_data.pickle` inside it as well.

## in the host real

You will still have a `C:\Users\Me\Google Drive\Projects` folder. In this folder the old and new files will appear.

## make the link between two realms

The link is done by the "volume" statement on you compose file, you will have : `C:\Users\Me\Google Drive\Projects:/data` on your "volume" part.

Comment: How would one go about doing this link as a Docker run command or better yet in a `docker-compose.yml` file? I read up on bind mounts but I'm not sure what to do exactly here

Comment: to use a volume directly without the docker-compose file you just use -v host_path:docker_path